# Cannot Update SharePoint Publishing Page Image

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am trying to update publishing Page image url but somehow after execute query command. its value saved as null

```
        ClientContext targetContext = new ClientContext ("REAL URL");
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File targetFile = targetContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl ("REAL URL");
        var targetPublishingPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage (targetContext, targetFile.ListItemAllFields);
        targetContext.Load (targetPublishingPage.ListItem);
        targetContext.ExecuteQuery ();
        targetFile.CheckOut ();
        targetPublishingPage.ListItem["PublishingPageImage"] = "REAL URL";
        targetPublishingPage.ListItem.Update ();
        targetContext.ExecuteQuery ();
```

Comment: Dear Down voter can you answer the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publishing Image field value is expected to be specified in the folliowing format: `<img src='{imageurl}'>`

**Example**

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    var pageFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
    var pageItem = pageFile.ListItemAllFields;
    pageItem["PublishingPageImage"] = "<img src='/PublishingImages/PageLogo.png'>";
    pageItem.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```